# Pandas: How can I make data frame with double columns?

Tags: python, pandas

This is how data frame looks (for `APPL`):
[image]

And there is another data frame of `DELL`, having same format with above.

What I want to create is like this:

```
                AAPL     |     DELL     |
            Open | Close | Open | Close |
2011-01-01   
2011-01-02
2011-01-03
    .
    .
```

How can I make this kind of data frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) if need all columns:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, keys=('AAPL','DELL'))
```

EDIT:

If need filter only `Open` and `Close` columns add `subset`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1[['Open', 'Close']], 
                df2[['Open', 'Close']]], axis=1, keys=('AAPL','DELL'))
```

---

```
cols = ['Open', 'Close']
df = pd.concat([df[cols], df1[cols]], axis=1, keys=('AAPL','DELL'))
```

Comment: `pd.concat([df[['Open', 'Close']], df1[['Open', 'Close']]], axis=1, keys=('AAPL','DELL'))` works :)

Comment: Sorry, I think you need all columns.